# Covariant derivative and isometries

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential

Let $(M, g)$ and $(N, h)$ be pseudo-Riemannian manifolds with Levi-Civita connections $\nabla^g$ and $\nabla^h$,
respectively. Let $\varphi : (M, g) \to (N, h)$ be an isometry. Show that
$\varphi_* \left(\nabla^g_X Y \right) = \nabla^h_{\varphi_*X}\varphi_*Y$
for all $X, Y ∈ \mathfrak{X}(M)$.

could someone show me how to prove this? For now, I know that maybe I should prove that the inner product of the left side is equal to the right side. And I am complete lost after that...

Comment: In your definition, is an isometry a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Hello, yes. it is a diffeomorphism

Answer (score 2):

If $\varphi$ is a a diffeomorphism, then $\varphi_* : \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathfrak{X}(N)$ is a bijection. Use [Koszul's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry#The_Koszul_formula), which uniquely determines the Levi-Civita connection:
\begin{align}
2h\left(\nabla^h_{\varphi_*X}{\varphi_*Y},\varphi_*Z\right) =& (\varphi_*X)\cdot h\left(\varphi_*Y,\varphi_*Z \right) + (\varphi_*Y)\cdot h\left(\varphi_*X,\varphi_*Z \right)\\
&- (\varphi_*Z)\cdot h\left(\varphi_*X,\varphi_*Y\right) +h\left([\varphi_*X,\varphi_*Y],\varphi_*Z\right) \\
& - h\left([\varphi_*X,\varphi_*Z],\varphi_*Y \right) - h \left([\varphi_*Y,\varphi_*Z],\varphi_*X \right).
\end{align}
Use the naturality of the Lie bracket (*i.e* $[\varphi_*X,\varphi_*Y] = \varphi_*[X,Y]$), the fact that $\varphi$ is an isometry (*i.e* $h=\varphi_*g$) and the chain-rule to show that the RHS is equal to
$$
\varphi_* \left(2g\left(\nabla^g_XY,Z \right) \right)
$$
and conclude with uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: I have a question, what is the RHS in your prove?

Comment: See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry#The_Koszul_formula): the fundamental theorem of (pseudo-)Riemannian geometry, which states the uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection, gives a way to compute the connection with this formula, called Koszul's formula. The RHS is just an application of this formula with the vector fields $\varphi_*X, \varphi_*Y$ and $\varphi_*Z$.