# Covariant derivative of conformal metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ a positive function. Find a relation
between the two covariant derivatives $\nabla^g$ and $\nabla^h$ of $g$ and $h= f\cdot g$.
Hint: The formula is nicer, if you write $f = e^{2u}$
for some $u \in  \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$.

For this problem, I have complete no clue. It would be nice if you could show me how to prove this

Comment: Use the formula for the covariant derivative associated with a Riemannian metric and calculate!

Comment: Hi! Welcome on MSE! I edited your question to have the right typesetting. Please learn some mathjax basis so that in the future you will be able to write properly your questions.

Comment: To answer directly you question: it is [again](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4164791/788724) a direct application of [Koszul's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry#The_Koszul_formula) for (pseudo-)Riemannian Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Conformal_change_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000005A-QINU%60%22'%7F) collects several formulas, with a section for conformal change of metric

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will see how to use mathjax

Answer (score 2):

I write $g=g$ and $h=\tilde{g}$ where $\tilde{g}=e^{2f}g$ for $f$ a diferentiable map. Then you have:
$\tilde{\nabla}_{X}Y=\nabla_{X}Y+(Xf)Y+(Yf)X-g(X,Y)\nabla f$

To prove it, just note:

Using the Koszul formula for $g$
\begin{equation*}
 \label{eq:Koszul}
 \begin{array}{rcl}
 2g(\nabla_X Y,Z)&=& X g(Y,Z) + Y g(X,Z) - Z g(X,Y) \\
 && + g([Z,X],Y) + g([Z,Y],X) + g([X,Y],Z).
 \end{array}
 \end{equation*}
And using again the Koszul formula for $\tilde{g}$, we get
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{array}{rcl}
 2e^{2f}g(\tilde{\nabla}_X Y,Z)&=& X( e^{2f}g(Y,Z)) + Y (e^{2f}g(X,Z)) - Z (e^{2f}g(X,Y)) \\
 && + e^{2f}g([Z,X],Y) + e^{2f}g([Z,Y],X) + e^{2f}g([X,Y],Z),
 \end{array}
 \end{equation*}
if we write the three first terms in the form $X( e^{2f}g(Y,Z))=2(Xf)e^{2f}g(Y,Z)+e^{2f}Xg(Y,Z)$ we arrive to
\begin{align*}
 2e^{2f}g(\tilde{\nabla}_X Y-\nabla_X Y,Z)&=2e^{2f}\{(Xf)g(Y,Z)+(Yf)g(X,Z)-(Zf)g(X,Y)\}
 \end{align*}
and this finishes our prove due to $Zf=g(\nabla f,Z)$.